# Calculate Positional Difference based on row for string values for two tables

Tags: google-sheets

Table 1:

| Position | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MCI |
| 2 | LIV |
| 3 | MAN |
| 4 | CHE |
| 5 | LEI |
| 6 | AST |
| 7 | BOU |
| 8 | BRI |
| 9 | NEW |
| 10 | TOT |

Table 2

| Position | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LIV |
| 2 | MAN |
| 3 | MCI |
| 4 | CHE |
| 5 | AST |
| 6 | LEI |
| 7 | BOU |
| 8 | TOT |
| 9 | BRI |
| 10 | NEW |

Output I'm looking for is
Position difference = 10 as that is the total of the positional difference. How can I do this in excel/google sheets? So the positional difference is always a positive even if it goes up or down. Think of it as a league table.

Table 2 New (using formula to find positional difference):

| Position | Team | Positional Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LIV | 1 |
| 2 | MAN | 1 |
| 3 | MCI | 2 |
| 4 | CHE | 0 |
| 5 | AST | 1 |
| 6 | LEI | 1 |
| 7 | BOU | 0 |
| 8 | TOT | 2 |
| 9 | BRI | 1 |
| 10 | NEW | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IFNA(ABS(INDEX(A:B,MATCH(E2,B:B,0),1)-D2),"-")
```

Assuming that table 1 is at columns A:B:

[image: Example output]

Comment: Hey, this works great for single a single character. Sorry I should've made it more clearer in my example, what is it is an actual team name like Golden State Warriors, here it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it, I updated my answer, I also added a little validation that'll show "-" if the team is not in both tables.